# UPDATE WHERE IN with LIMIT 1 updates multiple rows

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, queue

I'm trying to create a queue service that uses a table for queue items.
This is a query for getting one item and changing its status from 0 (pending) to 1 (in_progress):

```
UPDATE queue_items
SET status = 1
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT w.id
    FROM queue_items AS w
    WHERE (@delay >= w.execution_delay) AND (w.status = 0)
    ORDER BY w.priority DESC, w.id
    LIMIT 1
    FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
)
RETURNING  *
```

Everything works well except the weird fact that sometimes this query updates multiple rows at once, despite LIMIT 1.

queue_items.id - primary key.

Any idea how it can happen?

Comment: This can happen if you have several records with the same id in table queue_items

Comment: @S-Man id - is a primary key. it's unique

Comment: @MaximMarkov Have you tried using `EXISTS` instead of `IN`?

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, when Postgres decides to use the nested loop for joining the filtering subquery it can be evaluated multiple times and multiple rows being returned despite the limit.

Wrapping the subquery to CTE solved the issue.

```
WITH filter AS (
  SELECT w.id
  FROM queue_items AS w
  WHERE (@delay >= w.execution_delay) AND (w.status = 0)
  ORDER BY w.priority DESC, w.id
  LIMIT 1
  FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
)

UPDATE queue_items
SET status = 1
FROM filter
WHERE queue_items.id = filter.id
RETURNING  queue_items.*
```

Comment: If you make your CTE like this "WITH filter AS MATERIALIZED (..." it guarantees it will be run once and results materialized before it executes the next query, otherwise it will be integrated into the query and planned, which might result in a nexted loop again